# How to update Google Cloud Storage ACL using Cloud Storage API in Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-storage

I was studying the sample: https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/json-api-javascript-samples

It works well and one of its demonstrations is `getBucket/ObjectAccessControls`. But update ACL is not in the sample.

The closest document I could find was https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/bucketAccessControls/update?hl=zh-TW

But where should I put the "Request body" part? or use the generic `gapi.client.request`? So do I need to call `gapi.client.storage.bucket/objectAccessControls.insert` even if the generic `gapi.client.request` has been used?

Moreover, in the above document there is no description about where to put the ACL content, something like the xml scripts in https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/accesscontrol?hl=zh-tw

And also the cross origin settings: https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/cross-origin?hl=zh-tw